# Python recursive index changing

Tags: python-3.x, list, recursion, matrix

I am trying to arrange matrix in way that it will dynamically change the indexes.

I have tried to do it by means of for loop, however it only does once for each index.

```
def arrangeMatrix(progMatrix):
    for l in range(len(progMatrix)):
        for item in range(len(progMatrix[l])):
            if indexExists(progMatrix,l + 1,item) and progMatrix[l + 1][item] == " ":
                progMatrix[l + 1][item] = progMatrix[l][item]
                progMatrix[l][item] = " "
```

The original list is:

```
1   0       7   6   8
0   5           5   5
2   1               6
4   1   3   7        
1   1   1   7       5
```

And my code should fill all gapped indexes from up to bottom, however my result is:

```
1   0           6   8
0   5               5
2   1       7        
4   1   3   7       6
1   1   1   7   5   5
```

The actual result should be:

```
1   0               
0   5               8
2   1       7       5
4   1   3   7   6   6
1   1   1   7   5   5
```

Any help or hint is appreciated.Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is probably easier if you first iterate the columns, since the change that happens in one column is independent on what happens in other columns. Then, per column, you could iterate the cells from the bottom to the top and keep track of the y-coordinate where the next non-space should "drop down" to.

No recursion is needed.

Here is how that could be coded:

```
def arrangeMatrix(progMatrix):
    for x in range(len(progMatrix[0])):
        targetY = len(progMatrix)-1
        for y in range(len(progMatrix)-1,-1,-1):
            row = progMatrix[y]
            if row[x] != " ": # Something to drop down
                if y < targetY: # Is it really to drop any lower?
                    progMatrix[targetY][x] = row[x] # copy it down
                    row[x] = " " # ...and clear the cell where it dropped from 
                targetY -= 1 # since we filled the target cell, the next drop would be higher
```

Comment: Thank you for your help and explanation. That is very kind of you.